# Firebase "CurrentUser displayName" won't update with bottomsheet

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

My application has Firebase Authentication implemented and each user have to input their ***display name*** to register into the application.

Inside my application I want the user to be able to update this ***display name***.

The logic is very simple, user clicks '**Change Display Name**' button, a **ModalBottomSheet** appears where user can input his new display name and save it. But this way the screen **doesn't gets updated** when the display name is changed until I hot reload or restart the application.

[image]

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String displayName = _auth.currentUser.displayName;
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    String newDisplayName;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Current display name is:',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            Text(
              '$displayName',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Change Display Name'),
              onPressed: () {
                showModalBottomSheet(
                  isScrollControlled: true,
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets
                      child: Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            TextFormField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'New Display Name',
                              ),
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              onSaved: (value) {
                                newDisplayName = value;
                              },
                            ),
                            RaisedButton(
                              child: Text('Change'),
                              onPressed: () {
                                _formKey.currentState.save();
                              
                                _auth.currentUser
                                    .updateProfile(displayName: newDisplayName);

                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to call .reload in different places but the display name won't change until page is refreshed.

```
_auth.currentUser.reload();
```

EDIT: Solution thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/11921453/twelve

Wrap the manin widget with the following StreamBuilder and you will be able to retrieve the snapshot.data.displayName instantly.

```
child: StreamBuilder<User>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges(),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase has a stream to listen to user changes. Define this stream next to your _auth.

Wrap your widget-tree with au streambuilder and set the value to the defined stream.

Now the widget-tree gets rebuild every time the user data changes.